# Why is Ubuntu trying to install in UEFI when I have booted to the install media in Legacy BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, bios

I have a Windows install in Legacay BIOS, and I want to install Ubuntu in Legacy BIOS mode as well so grub will recognize Windows.

When I boot my USB drive, it shows the boot options of "UEFI Lexar Drive" and "Lexar Drive". I select the latter.

When I install the Ubuntu installer forces me to create an EFI partition, and the resulting install is in UEFI, and can not see windows 10 in grub or when I use os-prober.

How can I install Ubuntu 21.10 using legacy bios?

Comment: If the USB is booted as a legacy device then it won't install a UEFI operating system. Perhaps this option is failing and your BIOS is proceeding to the next option which is UEFI. Does your motherboard allow you to disallow UEFI completely? How did you create the bootable media?

Comment: On your disk is GPT partition table ?

Comment: If your system is UEFI, you probably should have Windows in UEFI boot mode. Best to make plans to convert, but Windows in UEFI mode will want gpt partitioning and conversion from MBR(msdos) to gpt will totally erase drive. Others have posted that installer now seems to automatically create an ESP. Perhaps for future use or maybe partitioning tool part of installer just assumes all systems are now UEFI, since only systems prior to 2012 were BIOS hardware.